# ¿Se puede instanciar una clase de otro proyecto?

Tags: laravel-5

Quisiera saber si es posible hacer el llamado de una función que se encuentra en una clase de otro proyecto.

Esta es la estructura de ambos proyectos:

```
.
├── Proyecto 1 (PHP)
│   └── CarpetaDeClases
│       └── ClaseALlamar
│
└── Proyecto 2 (LARAVEL 5)
    └── App
        └── Http
            └── Controllers
                └── ArchivoLlamaClase
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta corta con la información que das es **SI**.

> No conozco Laravel, y tendrá sus peculiaridades o facilidades, pero siendo PHP, está bastante estandarizado.

¿Como instancias la clase?

Pues tienes dos opciones dependiendo de la configuración:

**1.- Namespace**

Solo si la configuración del proyecto incluye a `Proyecto 1` dentro del autoload.
Y si la clase a llamar tiene especificado el `namespace`.

```
use Proyecto_1\CarpetaDeClases\ClaseALlamar;

class ArchivoLlamaClase
{
    public function loquesea() {
        $clase = new ClaseALlamar();
        // también directamente sin usar el operador use
        $clase = new \Proyecto_1\CarpetaDeClases\ClaseALlamar();
    }
}
```

**2.- A través de require o include**

La segunda opción es incluirla a través de include o require según te interese.

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/../../../Proyecto_1/CarpetaDeClases/ClaseALlamar.php';

class ArchivoLlamaClase
{
    public function loquesea() {
        $clase = new ClaseALlamar();
    }
}
```

Es cuestión de establecer las rutas correctas y tener el reporte de errores activado mientras editas las clases para observar las notificaciones en caso de lanzar algún error.

Si a pesar de tener las rutas correctamente lanza errores ya hay que entrar en ver permisos, configuración y demás parámetros del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo (A como te entiendo):

Suponiendo que tienes un Controlador:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

  public function getHome()
  {
    return view('pages.home');
  }

}
```

Y quieres usar la siguiente clase :

```
class PricesClass {
  public function getPrices() {
    return ['bronze' => 50, 'silver' => 100, 'gold' => 150];
  }
}
```

**Puedes poner una clase en sí en cualquier lugar que desee dentro de la carpeta *\App***

Diciendo esto,en este ejemplo, puedes guardar la clase como *APP\Classes\ PricesClass.php*. Entonces le agregas el namespace *App\Classes*.

Entonces quedaría así el uso de la clase:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Classes\PricesClass;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

  public function getHome()
  {
    $pricesClass = new PricesClass();
    $prices = $pricesClass->getPrices();
    return view('pages.home', compact('prices'));
  }

}
```

**Otra opción**

Por ejemplo tienes este ***archivo.php*** que no es una clase ni nada, solo una función:

```
<?php

function getPrices() {
  return ['bronze' => 50, 'silver' => 100, 'gold' => 150];
}
```

Puedes usar funciones de PHP como **include()** or **require()** sin olvidar la función **app_path()**.

Quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
 public function getHome()
    {
      include(app_path() . '\functions\archivo.php');
      $prices = getPrices();
      // ...
```

Puedes revisar la [fuente original](http://laraveldaily.com/how-to-use-external-classes-and-php-files-in-laravel-controller/) para un mejor entendimiento.